# How to use classes to control windows in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have been making applications for Mac with Objective-C for about a year now but due to not really understanding how to use classes properly I have only ever used the 'AppDelegate' files. I want to start using classes as soon as possible because from what I understand it's very bad practice to clump it in to one class. Basically, how do I have two windows, each controlled by it's own class. I understand how to make objects similar to NSString or something but don't understand how to have classes that control windows etc.

Thanks

Edit: Basically I want to know how to split up my application in to classes.

Comment: what do you mean by "control"?

Comment: You need to make this question more specific and concrete. How about starting with [searching the docs for "window"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=window), which turns up the [Window Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/WinPanel.html) as the top hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you need to create individual controller classes sporting their own IBOutlets and IBActions and hook these up to your UI elements. To split up an existing application into smaller classes requires some knowledge of Object Oriented programming.

Alternatively, you might benefit from reading this (or a similar) book:

'Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X' by Aaron Hillegass.

Comment: Thanks, yea I will probably by that book, I still need to wrap my head around some of the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for NSWindowController in the docs. You create a custom subclass of NSWindowController and a xib file for it. In the xib file, make sure you set the class on the File's Owner to your custom subclass, and make sure its window outlet is connected to the window in the xib. If all that sounds totally foreign, head for the books! =)

Then, in the code where you want to bring this window onto the screen, you create an instance of your custom subclass and associate it with the xib, like so:

```
MyCustomWindowController *controller = [[MyCustomWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"myxib"]
[controller showWindow:self];
```

The xib loading system will hook up all your custom outlets and actions on the new controller, and you can show it or do other wonderful NSWindowController things.